# How do you edit text messages/urls on HTC Desire

Tags: android

So I've been asked this question by another developer in work and I couldn't figure it out.  Now having a Desire myself, how the hell do you edit a text message that you are composing?  The same for a URL you may have made a typo in?  On the iPhone you would hold down on the area where you want to edit and a little zoom bubble would appear and the cursor would be where you want it allowing you to retype.  Can this even be done on Android devices?

Comment: It's not a programming question. You'd better ask such questions on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the trackball. The other way is to just tap your finger on the location in the text you'd like the caret positioned at.

The moving-zoom-bubble thing on iOS is I believe apple patented, so not available for the rest of the world, even though it's pretty obvious IMHO. That's software patents for you though.

Comment: Brilliant, so I guess we were being too heavy handed with it (it was a Samsung Galaxy tab).  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

On my Motorola Droid, you can tap on the screen in any textbox in order to set the cursor. It's difficult to get the cursor where you want it, but it can be done.